# Data Appending issue

Tags: python

I am trying to add combination of words in my existing string using **python**. To achieve this i have written below code.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/user/cloudera/rank_t/*"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
dumpoff = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", "-", "/user/cloudera/DATA"],stdin=PIPE)
obrInd = "0"
line1 = ""
for line in cat.stdout:
    runnno= line.split('|')[0]
    code = line.split('|')[1]
    idval = line.split('|')[2]

    if (code == "OBR"):
        obrInd = runnno
    line =line + "|"+"OBR_"+obrInd  
    dumpoff.stdin.write(line)
    print(line)
```

**My sample data:**

```
1|ORC||4002C3|4002C3||||||20141231|||1962
2|OBR|1||4002C3|197 HP, RX 16/L|||20141|20141||||||||196248||RJ||3711028|||||F
3|OBX|1|ST|2263||NEGATIVE FOR INTRAEPITHELIAL L.||||||F|||20141231|RJ @#L
4|NTE|1|L|NEGATIVE FOR INTRAEPITHELIAL LESION AND .
5|OBX|2|ST|1158||NIL||||||F|||20141231|RJ@#L
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1|ORC||4002C3|4002C3||||||20141231|||1962|
2|OBR|1||4002C3|197 HP, RX 16/L|||20141|20141||||||||196248||RJ||3711028|||||F|OBR_1
3|OBX|1|ST|2263||NEGATIVE FOR INTRAEPITHELIAL L.||||||F|||20141231|RJ @#L|OBR_1
4|NTE|1|L|NEGATIVE FOR INTRAEPITHELIAL LESION AND .|OBR_1
5|OBX|2|ST|1158||NIL||||||F|||20141231|RJ@#L|OBR_1
```

**Actual Output:**

```
    1|ORC||4002C3|4002C3||||||20141231|||1962|
    2|OBR|1||4002C3|197 HP, RX 16/L|||20141|20141||||||||196248||RJ||3711028|||||F
    |OBR_1
    3|OBX|1|ST|2263||NEGATIVE FOR INTRAEPITHELIAL L.||||||F|||20141231|RJ @#L
    |OBR_1
    4|NTE|1|L|NEGATIVE FOR INTRAEPITHELIAL LESION AND .
    |OBR_1
    5|OBX|2|ST|1158||NIL||||||F|||20141231|RJ@#L
    |OBR_1
```

the word that i am trying to append is appending in  new line i want it to get appending in the same line. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because each `line` has a `\n` at the end. You can strip the string with `.strip()`:

```
line = line.strip() + "|"+"OBR_"+obrInd
```

or

```
line = line.strip('\n') + "|"+"OBR_"+obrInd
```

if you care about white spaces at the begining/end of the line.

Comment: I tried your way but i am getting below error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
`

Comment: To strip a string use `.strip()` and not `.split()`

Comment: @Wombatz Thanks for the help.